# Get weight of words by occurence

Tags: math

Maybe this is related to math.stacexhange, but I am affraid, that I will get a formula in answer what I won't undersand.

I have products in our database, and I have products from different suppliers in another table.

What I want is to pair, these supplieres products to our products if it is possible, or show for me at least show me a list, where the matching is high.

I did iterate throught all the suppliers products, and explodes the product name by spaces, and store it in a table, and the count of the occurence.

The table seems like this.

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
|   id   |    word     | originalWord  | count |
+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| 220950 | Tracer      | Tracer        |   493 |
| 220951 | Destroyer   | Destroyer     |     3 |
| 220952 | Avago5050   | Avago5050     |     4 |
| 220953 | mouse       | mouse         |  2535 |
| 220954 | TRAMYS44916 | /TRAMYS44916/ |     2 |
| 220955 | GameZone    | GameZone      |    16 |
| 220956 | Enduro      | Enduro        |     3 |
| 220957 | AVAGO       | AVAGO         |    10 |
| 220958 | 5050        | 5050          |     4 |
| 220959 | optical     | optical       |  2370 |
| 220960 | USB         | USB           |  6160 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

and so on. Of course, in another table I stored, what is the product id for each word.

So what I want is to determine the weight of a word by occurence.

As you see, the word `TRAMYS44916` is occured only twice, almost certain that is a partnumber, so this is the most heavy word. It weight should be 1.

Let's say the most occured is USB with 6160 occurence, so it weight should be like 0.01 or something like that, I think.

What is the best way to get all the weights of the words?

There are other tables for other suppliers so dispersion is always change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of Naive Bayes text classification, so to determine which product should it belongs to, you can calculate tf-idf of all the words.

Then if you want to pair it from another product name, you can decompose it to words again and select the product id based on the highest term value, however maybe you should specify some threshold for this, because in some cases it would not be that clear.

tf-idf = ("number of word matches in product name"/"word count of product name") * log ("number of products" / "number of products that contains the word")

You can see how it is done in the example here (In your case the document will be the product full name): [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf#Example_of_tf.E2.80.93idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Example_of_tf.E2.80.93idf)

Example implementation in Java: https://guendouz.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/implementation-of-tf-idf-in-java/

Comment: Yes, I think this will be my friend. Thank you, now I do not need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just read the tf-idf wiki, I think it will be enough for us, So If I translated your formula back, it is mean, `"word count overall" * log ("number of document contains the word" / number of documents)` right?

Comment: actually idf is other way around, sorry for that, I will update it, it should be log("number of documents"/"number of documents that contains the word")

Comment: so if you have 10 products, and the term is only mentioned once: log(10/1) = 1, if it is mentioned in all 10 products: log(10/10) = 0. Then you multiply it how many times it is mentioned in the product name, that is the tf (this is "ignored" by idf). and you have tf-idf.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and update. So what I need is the `idf` not `tf-idf` right?

Comment: sorry I did a mistake that confused you in the equation and fixed it, you need the tf, that is how you get a value on a per document (product) basis.

Comment: Yes, later I realized it. Thank you.